# jQuery .click value change

Tags: jquery, forms, click

Can't get this basic .click event to work
Here is my code:

```
     $("#thebutton").click(function(){
     var text = $("input1").val();
     $("#input2").val(text);
     });
```

here is the codepen
http://cdpn.io/GFoxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `#` sign for [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), you also need to include jQuery properly as you are getting error *"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "*, this [article](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) could help you to understand

Change

```
var text = $("input1").val();
```

To

```
var text = $("#input1").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

See Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

You have not included jquery Library...

And then:

```
 var text = $("#input1").val()  //<--Missing id selector here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using id so use `#`

```
$("#thebutton").click(function(){
     var text = $("#input1").val(); //$("input1").val(); change this
     $("#input2").val(text);
     });
```

Comment: Fastastic, cheers guys, school boy error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#thebutton").click(function(){
     var text = $("#input1").val();
     $("#input2").val(text);
});
```